# Convert PoseNet TensorFlow.js params to TensorFlow Lite

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js

I'm fairly new to TensorFlow so I apologize if I'm saying something absurd.

I've been playing with the [PoseNet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet) model in the [browser](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.html) using TensorFlow.js. In this project, I can change the [algorithm and parameters](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet#config-params-in-posenetload) so I can get better results on the detection of certain poses. The most important params in my use case are the Multiplier, Quant Bytes and Output Stride.

So far so good, I have the results I want. However, I want to convert these results to [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/pose_estimation/overview) so I can use it in an iOS application. I managed to find the PoseNet model in a TensorFlow Lite file (tflite) and I even found an [iOS app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/posenet/ios) example provided by TensorFlow to I'm able to load up the model file and have it working on iOS.

The problem is...I'm unable to change the params (Multiplier, Quant Bytes and Output Stride) on the iOS app. I can't find it anywhere how I can do this. I've tried searching for these params in the iOS app source code, I've tried to find ways to convert a TensorFlow.js model to TensorFlow Lite so I can load the model with the params I want in the app but no luck.

I'm writing this post so maybe you guys can point me in the right direction so I'm able to "translate" what I have on TensorFlow.js to TensorFlow Lite.

**EDIT:**

This is what I've learned in the last couple of days:

TFLite is designed for serving fixed model with lightweight runtime. Thus, modifying model parameters on demand is not a design goal for it.

I looked at the TF.js code for PoseNet, and found similar design. It seems you can modify parameters, because they actually have different models for each params. https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/b72c10bdbdec6b04a13f780180ed904736fa52a5/posenet/src/checkpoints.ts#L37

TFLite models generally don't support dynamic parameters. Output stride Multiplier and Quant Bytes are fixed params when the neural network is created.

So what I want to do is to extract weights from TF.js model, and put then into existing MobileNet code.

And that's where I need help now. Could anyone point me in the direction to load and change the model so I can then convert it to tflite with my own params?

**EDIT2:**

I found a repo that is helping me convert TF.js models to TF Lite [Griffin98/posenet_tfjs2tflite](https://github.com/Griffin98/posenet_tfjs2tflite). I still can't define the Quant Bytes tho.